# Splitting up a test suite into a series of Locust.IO tasks

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I have a series of smoke tests that my company uses to validate its web-application.  These tests are written in Ruby.  We want to splits these tests into a series of tasks within locust.io. I am a newby when it comes to Locust.IO. I have written python code that can run these tasks one after the other in succession.  However, when make them locust.io tasks nothing is being reported in the stats window.  I can see the tests run in the console but the statistics never get updated.  What do I need to do?  Here is a snippet of the Locustfile.py I generate.

```
def RunTask(name, task):
  code, logs = RunSmokeTestTask(name, task)
  info("Smoke Test Task {0}.{1} returned errorcode {2}".format(name, task, code))
  info("Smoke Test Task Log Follows ...")
  info(logs)

class SmokeTasks(TaskSet):

  @task
  def ssoTests_test_access_sso(self):
    RunTask("ssoTests.rb", "test_access_sso")

  . . .
```

RunSmokeTestTask is what actually runs the task.  It is the same code that I am using when I invoke the task outside of Locust.IO.  I can see the info in the logfile.  Some of them fail but the statistics never update.  I know I am probably missing something silly.

Comment: Can you share how you are making your your http calls? It sounds like it's possible you're not using the Locust http client, which would automatically report the result of the calls to Locust. When you don't use Locust's client, you need to fire success/failure events manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually report the events. (edit: I realize now that maybe you were hoping that locust/python would be able to detect the requests made from Ruby, but that is not possible. If you are ok with just reporting the whole test as a single "request", then keep reading)

Add something like this to your taskset:

```
self.user.events.request_success.fire(request_type="runtask", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
```

You'll also need to measure the time it took. Here is a more complete example (but also a little complex):

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html#sample-xml-rpc-user-client

Note: TaskSets are an advanced (useless, imho) feature, you probably want to put the @task directly under a User, and the RunTask method as well.

something like:

```
class SmokeUser(User):
  def RunTask(self, name, task):
    start_time = time.time()
    code, logs = RunSmokeTestTask(name, task)
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    self.events.request_success.fire(request_type="runtask", name=name, response_time=total_time, response_length=0)
    info("Smoke Test Task {0}.{1} returned errorcode {2}".format(name, task, code))
    info("Smoke Test Task Log Follows ...")
    info(logs)

  @task
  def ssoTests_test_access_sso(self):
    self.RunTask("ssoTests.rb", "test_access_sso")
```